# Frama-C and XML parser

Tags: ocaml, frama-c

I'm developing a plugin in Frama-C. I want to parse an xml file.
I installed the package libxml-light-ocaml-dev but I get an error "Unbound module Xml" in compiling.
I don't know how to proceed to make the package visible to Frama-C. Or should I use another package?

Comment: The OCaml compiler option `-I` serves to make directories that contain libraries visible to the OCaml compiler when compiling a module that uses these libraries.

Comment: I'm not compiling with ocamlc directly but I'm using a frama-c makefile. So I compile with make. And my Makefile contains this :

FRAMAC_SHARE := $(shell frama-c -print-path)
FRAMAC_LIBDIR := $(shell frama-c -print-libpath)
PLUGIN_NAME = Ctt
PLUGIN_CMO = ctt_utils ctt_core ctt_trace ctt
include $(FRAMAC_SHARE)/Makefile.dynamic

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're using `Makefile.dynamic` as indicated in Frama-C's developer manual, there are a few variables that you have to tweak in order to compile and link your plug-in against external libraries:

- `PLUGIN_BFLAGS` allows to pass extra options to OCaml's bytecode compiler, such as `-I /my/path/to/xml/library`, `` -I `ocamlfind xml-light` ``, or `-I $(XMLLIGHTPATH)` where `XMLLIGHTPATH` is set up by your configure script (see also developer manual for that).
- `PLUGIN_OFLAGS` is the equivalent for native compilation
- `PLUGIN_EXTRA_BYTE` gives a list of files that your plug-in has to be linked against when compiled in bytecode, such as `xmllight.cma`
- `PLUGIN_EXTRA_OPT` is the native code equivalent, such as `xmllight.cmxa`